# NSSpeechRecognizer without Apple's view?

Tags: macos

NSSpeechRecognizer is great for what I'm doing, except that it's accompanied by that little circular view of Apple's! Is there any way to hide that view or provide my own?

[image: NSSpeechRecognizer GUI]

Comment: did you manage to solve this?